# Image not displayed using Paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Hello I am beginner to ruby on rails and i am making the application in which we can upload and then display the image of user but image is not uploading and displaying.
Here is my code:

My upload page code is:

```
  <%= form_for @userinfo , :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'  %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo , class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save Details", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

My show page code is :

```
  <%= image_tag @userinfo.photo.url %>
  <p>
     <strong>Name:</strong>
     <%= @userinfo.name %>
  </p>
```

My model code is:

```
  class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo
    validates_attachment_presence :photo
    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  end
```

My controller code is:

```
  class UserinfoController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @userinfo= Userinfo.new
    end
    def create
      @userinfo = Userinfo.new(user_params)    
      if @userinfo.save
        flash[:success] = "User created Successfully!!"
        redirect_to userinfo_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
    def show
       @userinfo = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :father_name, :mother_name, :contact_number, :photo)
    end
  end
```

The error i got from the log file is: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/photos/original/missing.png") " and on the show page it displays "missing" instead of displaying image.
I am beginner to this so tell me what i am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Which page is erroring?  If it's the show page then can you include your show action code from the controller as well?

Comment: do we have to pass `has_attached_file` attributes to `params.require(:userinfo).permit`

Comment: you didn't specify the :url and :path in the model?

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I am getting the error on show page. It's not displaying the image instead it displays "Missing" their.

Comment: @Deema: Which url and path i have to specify and how? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @Sontya: i did that params.require(:userinfo).permit(:has_attached_file) but still it is not working.

Comment: here's how I'm saving my 'img1' for an 'item' object:      has_attached_file :img1,  :url => "/assets/items/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/items/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
    validates_attachment_content_type :img1, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    validates_attachment_presence :img1

Comment: See this if it helps https://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-upload-file-using-paperclip-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such but a guide to debugging.

- look in the log to see what is coming through to the show action in `params[:id]`
- in your console, load the `Userinfo` with that id, like `userinfo = Userinfo.find(123)`
- in the console, do `userinfo.photo` and `userinfo.photo.url` - do these look right?

  - if they do look ok, check that the file is in the location they are pointing to.  File paths are relative to your public folder.
  - if they don't look right, then the problem may be that they haven't actually uploaded properly in the first place.  Check that your uploading process is working properly and is properly setting the image association with the Userinfo object.

Answer (score 0):

i think you would have defined a default_url of the attachment such as

```
:default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

you need to remove it out and use the basic definition which works 99.99%.

```
attr_accessible :avatar
has_attached_file :avatar,
:url  => "/assets/images/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
##user defined path
:path => :rails_root/public/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
##commenting the datault url
##:default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

**EDITED ANSWER:-**

`So for a model user_info having avatar ..the view part with form_f`or

```
form_for(@user_info,url:your_post_path) do |f|
## use html instead
  <input type="file" name="user_info[avatar][]" multiple>
##or use helper instead
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: when i did this it gives the error "undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x007f75e8a906e0>". It is because rails 4+ version not support "attr_accessible". After removing that line and then when i added the image and submit the form it gives the error no file selected. This is why i don't know please tell me.